# Notification for user in user account opencart

Tags: notifications, opencart, status, user-accounts

Thanks for anyone who helps or points me in the right direction.

I want to show a pending notification to user in their my account page after login. This notification will show only when their any order status is pending. After changing any other status from admin will remove that notification.

This notification will show like:

**YOUR ORDER ID:
ORDER STATUS: 
and [ A button with custom Url]**

if multiple order then will show multiple order id. 
My Open cart Version 1.5.6.3 with custom Theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    $this->load->model('account/order');
    $results = $this->model_account_order->getOrders();

    foreach ($results as $result) {
        $product_total = $this->model_account_order->getTotalOrderProductsByOrderId($result['order_id']);
        $voucher_total = $this->model_account_order->getTotalOrderVouchersByOrderId($result['order_id']);
        if( $result['status'] =! 5){ // 5 order status means its completed
            $this->data['orders'][] = array(
            'order_id'   => $result['order_id'],
            'name'       => $result['firstname'] . ' ' . $result['lastname'],
            'status'     => $result['status'],
            'date_added' => date($this->language->get('date_format_short'), strtotime($result['date_added'])),
            'products'   => ($product_total + $voucher_total),
            'total'      => $this->currency->format($result['total'], $result['currency_code'], $result['currency_value']),
            'href'       => $this->url->link('account/order/info', 'order_id=' . $result['order_id'], 'SSL'),
            'reorder'    => $this->url->link('account/order', 'order_id=' . $result['order_id'], 'SSL')
            );  
        }

    }
```

In account.tpl add this code

```
      <div id="resent_order" class="recent_order">
            <a style="float:right; margin-bottom:15px;" href="<?php echo $manage_order; ?>" class="button">Pending orders</a>
<h4>Recent Order</h4>
                <ul style="clear:both;">
                <?php if( isset($orders) && count($orders > 0 ) ){ 

                   foreach ($orders as $order) { ?>
                    <li>
                    <div><strong>Order:#</strong><?php echo $order['order_id']; ?></div>
                    <div><strong>Date:</strong> <?php echo $order['date_added']; ?></div>
                    <div><strong>Amount:</strong> <?php echo $order['total']; ?></div>
                    <div><strong>Status:</strong> <?php echo $order['status']; ?></div>
                    <div class="editPan"><a class="" title="Edit" href="<?php echo $order['href']; ?>">Edit</a></div>
                    </li>

                <?php }   ?>

                <?php }else{?> <li>You have no pending orders.</li><?php }  ?>


                </ul>

            </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind answer. Here some problem. It's working without " if( $result['status'] =! 5) " . if i put this the result only show  "You have no recent orders." If i don't use " if( $result['status'] =! 5)" it show all order. Any idea how to solve this issue.

Comment: set limit in the query 0,5 or 0,10